# Implement multiple section in layout.cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net, layout, asp.net-core-mvc

Assume that I have a partial layout called "_Layout.cshtml" and I have a sidebar call "Sidebar.cshtml" both of them are located in "/Views/Shared".
I have few pages such as Login, Index,Account Maintenance, Manage Course and etc.
I would like to make that "Sidebar.cshtml" appear in "Account Maintenance.cshtml" and "Manage Course.cshtml" but the "Index.cshtml" and "Login.cshtml" should not appear the "Sidebar.cshtml".

I have tested implemented the `@RenderSection` in the "_Layout.cshtml" but it does not render and I know the "_Layout.cshtml" is a partial view. In this case, how can I achieve the assumption that I attempt to achieve.

Image illustration: "Left Bar" identifies as "Sidebar"
P/S: New to .NET Core

[image]

Code for _Layout.cshtml

```
 <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
               @RenderSection("sidebar", false)
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>
```

Code for Sidebar.cshtml

```
@{
    Layout = "_Layout.cshtml";
}
@section sidebar{
    
    <nav class="col-md-2 d-none d-md-block bg-light sidebar">
            <div class="sidebar-sticky">
                <ul class="nav flex-column">
                    <li class="nav-item nav-link">
                        <img src="https://facebook.com/static/logo/cs_logo.png?v=1" class="rounded-circle" style="height: auto; max-width: 100%">
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item nav-link">
                        Role: <br><strong>22</strong>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item nav-link">
                        Name:<br><strong>23qe</strong>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item nav-link">
                        User ID:<br><strong>324eef</strong>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item nav-link">
                        Last online:<br><strong>dsffsdf</strong>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, sidebar.cshtml is defining sections. This would make sense if you `return View("sidebar.cshtml")` in your controller. But you want to use another view to get content from sidebar, so the sections should be defined on the other view, not in sidebar.cshtml.

For example, you are calling Account/Maintenance, so let layout to define sections and here we need to provide content to fill these sections.

In Views/Account/**Maintenance.cshtml**

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<span>Body text</span>
@section sidebar{
    @{ 
        await Html.RenderPartialAsync("~/Views/Shared/sidebar.cshtml"); 
    }
}
```

In Views/Shared/**Sidebar.cshtml** just provide the content:

```
<nav class="col-md-2 d-none d-md-block bg-light sidebar">
    <div class="sidebar-sticky">
        <ul class="nav flex-column">
            <li class="nav-item nav-link">
                <img src="https://facebook.com/static/logo/cs_logo.png?v=1" class="rounded-circle" style="height: auto; max-width: 100%">
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item nav-link">
                Role: <br><strong>22</strong>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item nav-link">
                Name:<br><strong>23qe</strong>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item nav-link">
                User ID:<br><strong>324eef</strong>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item nav-link">
                Last online:<br><strong>dsffsdf</strong>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

In **AccountController**:

```
public IActionResult Maintenance()
{
    return View();
}
```

So that, sidebar would show in Maintenance, because the view provides content for that section and uses _Layout that defines the section.

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<html>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderSection("sidebar", false)
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If I would like to embed the Sidebar inside the _Layout.cshtml because the Sidebar mostly will be used by several pages. Also, it only does not being used by several pages.

Comment: In _Layout.cshtml, the section `sidebar` is not mandatory. This is specified by passing `false` argument in `@RenderSection("sidebar", false)`. So if you want a view to have sidebar, just include this section like I did in Maintenance.cshtml. Otherwise don't include it.

Comment: It does not render after I added @RenderSection("sidebar", false) in my _Layout.cshtml

Comment: I have tested above code and worked fine in .Net Core 3.1. May be there's something different in your code.

Comment: _Layout.cshtml: ~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml ||| Sidebar.cshtml:  ~/Views/Shared/Sidebar.cshtml |||  Home's index View: ~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml

Comment: That's the same locations I have. But I have changed the content of view Sidebar.cshtml as explained in my post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228701/discussion-between-miracle-hades-and-daniel-manta).